# Is there a 2 variable function whose graph would look like a cube?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

This is really out of pure curiosity, but seeing as though bivariable functions are graphed in 3d, what would be the function whose graph would most resemble a cube shape?

Comment: $|x|=|y|=|z|=1$ can works?

Comment: If the graph were a cube then lots vertical lines would intersect the graph in more than one point, contradicting the definition of a function.

Comment: @zhw Good point, I didn't think about it. Just like it's possible to graph a function that looks like a half-sphere but not the whole sphere.